# String equal to "0" in PHP

Tags: php

I have a function that takes an input, where `$input` comes from a MySQL database and is either an integer, a string, or null value, and returns one of three strings based on the following conditions:

- If it is an int that's equal to 0, return something
- Elseif it is an empty string, return something else
- Else return something else

My code looks like this:

```
if ($input == "") {
  return "case1";
}
elseif ($input == "0") {
  return "case2";
}
else {
  return "case3";
}
```

After echoing each input and comparing the output, it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? I've tried using every combination of "0" and 0, == and ===.

In testing, whole numbers and strings work, an so do empty strings. But an input of integer 0 does returns case3.

Comment: What is the input that you supplied in your tests, and which ones did not provide the output you expected?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* -- when everything else fails, read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: PHP uses dynamic typing, so "", 0, and FALSE are all equivalent. You need to use === in your comparison.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

This page explains how the types convert: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Have you tried with `$input === 0`? This check type and value

Comment: I know there is a dupe for this. Just gotta find it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php